# How to fix memory leak in GetPreviewFrameAsync

Tags: uwp, mediacapture

I have code based on this sample; https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CameraGetPreviewFrame.  Every time the line;

```
await _mediaCapture.GetPreviewFrameAsync(_currentVideoFrame);
```

is hit we seem to leak memory.  What am I not tidying up?  I have also tried creating the template frame each time and disposing and nulling it on each loop - this doesn't seem to work either.

I have gone back to the original sample from Microsoft and it seems to leak too.  Here is my code;

```cs
await Task.Run(async () =>
{
    try
    {
        var videoEncodingProperties = 
            _mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.GetMediaStreamProperties
                (MediaStreamType.VideoPreview) as VideoEncodingProperties;

        Debug.Assert(videoEncodingProperties != null, nameof(videoEncodingProperties) + " != null");

        _currentVideoFrame = new VideoFrame(BitmapPixelFormat.Gray8,
            (int) videoEncodingProperties.Width,
            (int) videoEncodingProperties.Height);

        TimeSpan? lastFrameTime = null;

        while (_mediaCapture.CameraStreamState == CameraStreamState.Streaming)
        {
            token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

            await _mediaCapture.GetPreviewFrameAsync(_currentVideoFrame);

            if (!lastFrameTime.HasValue ||
                lastFrameTime != _currentVideoFrame.RelativeTime)
            {
                await CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync
                    (CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
                    () =>
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            Debug.Assert(_currentVideoFrame != null,
                                        $"{nameof(_currentVideoFrame)} != null");

                            var bitmap = _currentVideoFrame.SoftwareBitmap.AsBitmap();

                            float focalLength = _cameraOptions == CameraOptions.Front ? AppSettings.FrontCameraFocalLength : AppSettings.RearCameraFocalLength;

                            _frameProcessor.ProcessFrame(bitmap, focalLength);
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            Debug.WriteLine($"Exception: {ex}");
                        }
                    });

                lastFrameTime = _currentVideoFrame.RelativeTime;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"Exception: {ex}");
    }
},
token);
```

This should simply get frames and put them through the `_frameProcessor.ProcessFrame()` call, but even when that does nothing (and I cut out everything except the GetPreviewFrameAsync) it leaks.

To repeat the problem, download the sample from; https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CameraGetPreviewFrame.  Run the sample in the debugger with diagnostic tools (Debug->Windows->Show Diagnostic tools) remotely to a Surface Pro 4 (i5-6300U @2.4GHz) under Windows 10 v 1903 (18362.175).  Turn on show frame check box and watch the memory as you press the GetPreviewFrameAsync button.  The memory looks as follows where each uptick is me pressing the button;

[image: Memory Leak]

Comment: Could you share more about how to check the memory leak?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Sure; I have added some information to repeat the problem in the main body of the question

Comment: Interestingly my desktop PC running the same code and a USB camera (which also shows the problem on the Surface Pro 4) does not show the problem - my desktop PC is Win 10 v1809 (17763.504)

Comment: Ok, I got it, I will test it, if the problem really exist, I will report to related team

Comment: Please check this issue [report](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/winrt-api/issues/1066) that host in Github.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT: thanks, we had already seen that one; but I don't think the video card (which seems to be the solution there) is really the issue here, given that it is happening on a Surface Pro 4 which we can't change the video card (and happens on my desktop with the built-in card) It does also seem to occur only on the latest Win10 release: v1903. v1809 seems fine.  We have reverted a Surface Pro and the leak goes away.

Comment: Ok,I will discuss with team.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195245/discussion-between-nico-zhu-msft-and-stephen-starkie).

Comment: Thanks for reporting this issue, our engineering team is investigating this issue, I will update it here once there is any update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the [MediaFrameReader API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.capture.frames.mediaframereader) works around this bug well in our code, and is perhaps slightly more responsive.  Microsoft have now added a note to the [GetPreviewFrameAsync documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.capture.mediacapture.getpreviewframeasync) to point to this.

This works for us;

```cs
...
private MediaFrameReader _mediaFrameReader;
...

private async Task InitializeCameraAsync()
{
    if (_mediaCapture == null)
    {
         _mediaCapture = new MediaCapture();
         var frameSourceGroups = await MediaFrameSourceGroup.FindAllAsync();
         var selectedGroup = frameSourceGroups.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id.Equals(_camera.UwpDeviceInfo.Id));

         try
         {
             var mediaInitSettings = new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings
             {
                 SourceGroup = selectedGroup,
                 VideoDeviceId = _camera.UwpDeviceInfo.Id,
                 AudioDeviceId = string.Empty,
                 StreamingCaptureMode = StreamingCaptureMode.Video,
                 MemoryPreference = MediaCaptureMemoryPreference.Cpu
             };

             await _mediaCapture.InitializeAsync(mediaInitSettings);

             _isInitialized = true;
         }
         catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
         {
...
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
...
         }
...

         // Set-up for frameProcessing
         var sourceInfo = selectedGroup?.SourceInfos.FirstOrDefault(info =>
             info.SourceKind == MediaFrameSourceKind.Color);
...                   
         var colorFrameSource = _mediaCapture.FrameSources[sourceInfo.Id];
         var preferredFormat = colorFrameSource.SupportedFormats
             .OrderByDescending(x => x.VideoFormat.Width)
             .FirstOrDefault(x => x.VideoFormat.Width <= 1920 &&
                  x.Subtype.Equals(MediaEncodingSubtypes.Nv12, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

         await colorFrameSource.SetFormatAsync(preferredFormat);

         _mediaFrameReader = await _mediaCapture.CreateFrameReaderAsync(colorFrameSource);
     }
...
}

...

private void _mediaFrameReader_FrameArrived(MediaFrameReader sender, MediaFrameArrivedEventArgs args)
{
...
        var mediaFrameReference = sender.TryAcquireLatestFrame();
        var videoMediaFrame = mediaFrameReference?.VideoMediaFrame;
        var softwareBitmap = videoMediaFrame?.SoftwareBitmap;

        if (softwareBitmap != null && _frameProcessor != null)
        {
            if (_mediaCapture.CameraStreamState == CameraStreamState.Streaming)
            {
...
                _frameProcessor.ProcessFrame(SoftwareBitmap.Convert(softwareBitmap, 
                        BitmapPixelFormat.Gray8).AsBitmap(), _camera);
...
            }
        }
...
    }
}
```